# sbt not able to find a "main" class from runMain but sees it from run

Tags: sbt

When using `sbt run`  as follows:

```
sbt "project epa-recon" "run"
```

We see that two main's are found:

```
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list

Multiple main classes detected, select one to run:

 [1] com.lash.epa.recon.EPAReconApp
 [2] com.lash.epa.recon.EPAReconApp47D
```

So then we should be able to use `runMain` .. no?

```
sbt "project epa-recon" "runMain com.lash.epa.recon.EPAReconApp"
```

well .. *no ..*

```
[warn] Multiple main classes detected.  Run 'show discoveredMainClasses' to see the list
java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last epa-recon/compile:runMain for the full output.
[error] (epa-recon/compile:runMain) No main class detected.
```

These messages are contradictory.   So .. any insights into what were actually the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran the exact syntax you provided in the question, and it worked. Using sbt 1.2.3 on Linux.

```
sbt "project subproject1" "runMain com.myco.SomeClassName"
```

Comment: are there multiple `main` classes in your project?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple main classes (Scala `object`s)

Comment: .. and with `def main(args: Array[String])` ?

Comment: Yes, `def main(args: Array[String]): Unit`

Comment: well i'm 3 yrs removed from that project and at a different company so I can't really verify . i'll go ahead and award in lack of a means to validate.